# How to have a function argument as a parameter to a macro in C

Tags: c, function, macros

I want to pass an argument that is a function into a macro, and it's obvious from compiler message errors I'm not doing it right:

```
#define mu_run(func()) func() == 0 ? printf_green("Test passed: %s\n", #func()) : printf_red("Test failed: %s at line %d", #func(), mu_check())
```

The error I get is: "(" may not appear in macro parameter list
#define mu_run(func()) func() == 0 ? printf_green("Test passed: %s\n", #func()) : printf_red("Test failed: %s at line %d", #func(), mu_check())

I don't know what else to do to it, I've tried replacing it with 'func' with no parenthesis, but I'm not sure if that's correct either.

Comment: You need to remove the parentheses in two places: `mu_run(func)` and `#func`

Comment: And I would add parentheses around the entire ternary expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pre-processor, when handling macros, just substitutes tokens - almost like a copy and paste of text from the declaration of the macro into the expansion.

If you wanted to make a macro that just calls a given function, you would have this:

```c
#define call_function(x) x()
```

Invoking this with `call_function(foo)` would expand to `foo()`.

You would not want:

```c
#define call_function(x()) x()
```

The `()` are something you add in the expansion (assuming you want to call the function), not in the declaration.

So you need to remove the parentheses after `func`, both in the macro declaration, and its expansion (when used as a string):

```c
#define mu_run(func) func() == 0 ? printf_green("Test passed: %s\n", #func) \
  : printf_red("Test failed: %s at line %d", #func, mu_check())
```

As also noted in comments, you should enclose the entire expansion in parentheses, like so:

```c
#define mu_run(func) (func() == 0 ? printf_green("Test passed: %s\n", #func) \
  : printf_red("Test failed: %s at line %d", #func, mu_check()))
```

This will protect you from possible problems with operator precedence when you do something like:

```c
mu_run(func1) && mu_run(func2)
```